# Still trying to Pass a PHP array to a JQuery function inside foreach loop (into Bootstrap3 modal)

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a php page with a foreach loop. I have figured out how to pass a single variable while in the loop to a JQuery function properly and have it work. I'm working in Bootstrap3 and am passing the variable into a modal window. Now I want to do it through an array and I am stumped. I have scoured the internet and this site, and I think I'm on the right track, but I'm missing something.

PHP and HTML:

```
 <?php
    $mapinfo = array(
        "pos" => $parkrow['pos'],
        "name" => $parkrow['name'],
        "address" => $parkrow['address'],
        "city" => $parkrow['city'],
        "state" => $parkrow['state'],
        "zip" => $parkrow['zip']
    );
?>
```

Parkrow was already defined...

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="<?php echo json_encode($mapinfo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>"><img src="images/locmaps/<?php echo $parkrow['parkid']; ?>.jpg" alt="map to <?php echo $parkrow['parkid'] ?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

In the link above I'm taking the PHP Array $mapinfo, encoding it, and sending it through the link. This worked (minus the encoding) with a single PHP variable, but is not working with the array.

JQuery:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {


  var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
  var mapinfo = button.data('whatever');

  alert(mapinfo.name);  ...
```

I've tried doing the encode in the Jquery, I've tried putting a script inside the href (a bad idea, I'm sure). I've tried encoding it in the php file and assigning it to it's own PHP variable and passing that. I'm totally stumped.

I do not want to do an AJAX request if at all possible - the overhead on this is already very high and adding to it would probably be a problem.

The conversation below SEEMED to solve the problem, but when I tested it properly, I still only got the information from the last item in the loop no matter which button I pushed. For instance if I pushed the "see map" button for the third park, I got the map for the last park. I'm still stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $mapinfo = array(
        "pos" => $parkrow['pos'],
        "name" => $parkrow['name'],
        "address" => $parkrow['address'],
        "city" => $parkrow['city'],
        "state" => $parkrow['state'],
        "zip" => $parkrow['zip']
    );
?>
```

and your button (do not write `data-whatever` here)

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" <img src="images/locmaps/<?php echo $parkrow['parkid']; ?>.jpg" alt="map to <?php echo $parkrow['parkid'] ?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

And instead of writing below code in your JS file, write it into PHP file instead.

```
<script>
var myData = <?php echo json_encode($mapinfo) ?>;
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {


 var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
 var mapinfo = myData;

 alert(mapinfo.name);  ..
```

Maybe your need single-quotes around that `'<?php echo json_encode($mapinfo) ?>'`

Comment: I don't understand some of your answer. "and your button (do not write data-whetever here)" what are you saying? And why do I want to move my JavaScript from my JS file to a PHP file?  I tried the single quotes suggestion, sadly it didn't work.

Comment: `do not write data-whetever here` I said because you want a JS variable to have a value generate by PHP so your will have to write the entire JS code into the PHP file as I seggested

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix in php into a .js file, the way you would with a normal .php file, since the .js file is not preprocessed by the .php engine the way your .php files are.

The most typical way to do this--including php in a js file--is to just have inline JS (stuff between  tags) in your .php file. Then it will work as expected. 
So if you use js or php both in single file then you in .php file it not posible in .js file.`

> try this you can solve your problem

`

```
   <?php
    $mapinfo = array(
        "pos" => $parkrow['pos'],
        "name" => $parkrow['name'],
        "address" => $parkrow['address'],
        "city" => $parkrow['city'],
        "state" => $parkrow['state'],
        "zip" => $parkrow['zip']
    );
?>
```

> your  Parkrow defined...

```
<a href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-whatever="<?php echo json_encode($mapinfo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>"><img src="images/locmaps/<?php echo $parkrow['parkid']; ?>.jpg" alt="map to <?php echo $parkrow['parkid'] ?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

> then write the jquery code in php file using  tag

```
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
            var myData = <?php echo json_encode($mapinfo) ?>;
            $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {


             var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
             var mapinfo = myData;

             alert(mapinfo.name);  ..
});
             </script>
```

Comment: Okay I'm trying this, but what I get is my console log stating that "$ is not defined"

Comment: load jquery file  using this <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">

Comment: Your link was cut off. I'm using <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script> Is there a benefit to using your link? If so, can yo please provide the whole link?

Comment: And I have a fallback:<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="includes/js/jquery.1.11.2.js"><\/script>')</script>

Comment: you use bootstrap model but not load required js and css ?

Comment: I'm loading js and css. It's a big file, I'm only giving parts.  I'm trying now to execute the jquery inside the php file. I've never done that before. I'm having some trouble with the syntax. If I just put <script> tags around it nothing is happening. I looked online and saw that I should try echoing the script, but I am not having any luck with that either. Could you please give a specific example of how to put the script into the PHP file?

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to call this "answered". My day job took over my life for awhile and I couldn't come back to work on it. Now this worked. THANK YOU SO MUCH.